# popup window pref android

Tags: android, preferences

I want to implement an about box in my wallpaper. For that, I want a window to show up which contains the information when a user clicks on it.

None of the available controls like checkbox, listview etc. can be used for this......
I also tried to make a Dialog Pref by following advice from some other questions I looked at but ended up with a dialog that just does not seem appropriate for an about box.
My DialogPref:

```
public class DialogPref extends DialogPreference {

    public DialogPref(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        persistBoolean(positiveResult);
    }

}
```

So can you help me implement a popup window for an about box?